# Setting list of child objects to parent object using it's setter method

Tags: java

I have Employee class like this

```
public class Employee{
           private int id;
           private List<Address>  address;
    //getter
      public List<Address> getAddress() {
        return address;
      }
    //setter
      public void setAddress(List<Address> address) {
        this.address = address;
      }
   }
```

I am getting list of address by calling other abstract methods which gets me address based on condition

```
mapToAddress(//some condition) //gets me permanent address employee

mapTOAddress(//some condition) //gets me present address employee
```

i have object of Employee so i want to set this two address object to Employee using its setter method

```
    employee.setAddress(//what i need to write here to set the list of address objects to employee object);
```

I need to set Address objects to Employee object using its setter method.please help me on this

Comment: Just pass the call to the other method as an argument like `employee.setAddress(mapToAddress(//some condition));`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to add addresses to an `Employee` object. You can create a method that adds `Address` objects to your list:

```java
public void addAddress(Address a) {
   this.address.add(a);
}
```

Or if you'd like to add a list of addresses:

```java
public void addAddresses(List<Address> addresses) {
  this.address.addAll(addresses);
}
```

Hope it helps :)

**EDIT**: If you still want to use the `setAddress` method, you could use the code above from `addAddresses(List<Address> addresses)`. However, that could be confusing, semantically speaking.